# Animate Controls down with change to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationbar, autolayout

I have a UINavigationController with standard UINavigationBar. When presenting certain UIViewControllers and orientations, the UINavigationBar may or may not appear and it may or may not have a prompt element. This means that the bar height changes frequently.

I have some subviews below the UINavigationBar set with NSLayoutConstraints to topLayoutGuide. It generally lays out as expected, adjusting vertical position of the subviews appropriately based on the height of the UINavigationBar. What it does not do is move the subviews at times when the UINavigationBar is animated after the view is already displayed.

Specifically, coming from a state with UINavigationBar hidden, transition to a UIViewController which does not hide the navigation bar to one which does. The view displays, then navigation bar animates into place. The subviews do not move down. If I rotate the device, every things lays out appropriately again. Only when animating the navigation bar in and out or to display/hide the prompt I not find a hook to reevaluate the constraints.

I tried `[self.view updateConstraints]` and `[self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded]` in various places such as viewDidAppear, viewDidLayoutSubviews. Nothing seems to update that topLayoutConstraint.

I am familiar with edge restraints, translucent navigation bar and other various methods of keeping the entire view from appearing under the navigation bar. I do want to keep view full size and I want the translucent bar so these are not solutions for me. It seems the constraints should handle this automatically, hence the "auto" in auto layout.

To simplify, for recreation, UINavigationController with rootViewcontroller showing normal navigation bar with just a title. In viewDidLoad of the next presented viewController I have `[self.navigationContoller setPrompt:self.myPrompt]`. The view is presented, when the prompt is set, the navigation bar grows larger. Some labels below the bar are set with relation to topLayoutGuide, which places them correctly initially. I expect they would move down when the bar grows. Rotate device back and forth, they now layout correctly. Pop the viewController and push back to top, repeats as above.

Comment: I'm not able to recreate your problem. Can you be more specific about the situation where the problem occurs? What code do you have to hide and show the navigation bar, and where is it?

Comment: I will look it over to be more specific. There are a lot of other things going on amidst the navcontroller. This was kind of an incidental thing that I always thought would be simple to fix once I went back to it. I am surprised that it has given me this much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out it was all me. After trying all manner of forcing layout updates in all sorts of ways, the solution was to move the [myView setPrompt:myPrompt] out of viewDidLoad and call it in viewDidAppear instead.

Works completely as expected. Navbar grows, subviews shift and shrink as needed. Now I have to hunt down all the experimental code I plastered everywhere trying to do it wrong.